# Django TypeError : __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

Here is a class code from `views.py`:

```
class Ask(CreateView):
    template_name = 'f/ask.html'
    form_class = QuestionForm
    success_url = '/f/ask/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        content = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return content
```

and this is my urls.py code

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from . import views, converter

register_converter(converter.HexConverter, 'hex')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.QuestionView),
    path('ask/', views.Ask),
    path('<hex:pk>/', views.QuestionCurrent, name='question_current'),
]
```

It says `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`, but that code I took from book, so I don't think it is wrong or something.

Comment: …and the full error traceback!

Comment: Could be that the book version of django and the version of django, or other libraries, you are using have changed. That is not a uncommon problem. Is the error pointing to this `register_converter`?

Comment: no, it is not pointing to register_converter

Answer (score 7):

Add [`.as_view()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) to your paths in `urls.py` *(as they are `class` based paths)*:

From:

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from . import views, converter

register_converter(converter.HexConverter, 'hex')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.QuestionView),
    path('ask/', views.Ask),
    path('<hex:pk>/', views.QuestionCurrent, name='question_current'),
]
```

To:

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from . import views, converter

register_converter(converter.HexConverter, 'hex')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.QuestionView.as_view()),
    path('ask/', views.Ask.as_view()),
    path('<hex:pk>/', views.QuestionCurrent.as_view(), name='question_current'),
]
```

---

From the documentation:

> `classmethod as_view(**initkwargs)`
>
> Returns a callable view that takes a request and returns a response:
>
> `response = MyView.as_view()(request)`
>
> The returned view has view_class and `view_initkwargs` attributes.
>
> When the view is called during the request/response cycle, the `setup()` method assigns the `HttpRequest` to the view's request attribute, and any positional and/or keyword arguments captured from the URL pattern to the args and kwargs attributes, respectively. Then `dispatch()` is called.